# Mocking Java 8 lamba function with Mockito 2

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, java-8, mockito

I am using JDBI 3 and have written the following utility function.

```
public class JdbiHelper {
    // ...

    public <T, DAO> T fetch(final Function<DAO, T> function, Class<DAO> daoClass) {
        return dbi.withHandle(handle -> {
           final DAO dao = handle.attach(daoClass);
           try {
               return function.apply(dao);
           }
           finally {
               handle.close();
           }
        });
    }
}
```

which I can call in methods like this

```
public Optional<Account> findByEmailAddress(final String emailAddress) {
    if (!exists(emailAddress))
        return Optional.empty();
    return jdbiHelper.fetch(dao -> ofNullable(dao.selectByEmailAddress(emailAddress)), AccountDAO.class);
}

private boolean exists(final String emailAddress) {
    return jdbiHelper.fetch(dao -> dao.count(emailAddress) > 0, AccountDAO.class);
}
```

I am trying to write a test for the `findByEmailAddress` mocking `jdbiHelper` using Mockito 2 but cannot work out how to mock the dao -> part of the method.

I've tried using `jdbiHelper.fetch(any(Function.class), eq(AccountDAO.class))` but as there are two different expectations of what to return it fails trying to cast one or the other.

Passing in a mocked Function causes a NPE as the dao param is null.

Comment: One quick and dirty way is to use multiple returns corresponding to the order of the calls, eg `when(mockHelper.fetch(any(), eq(AccountDAO.class))).thenReturn(true, Optional.of(new Account(...)));`. The first response will match the call for `exists` and the second one for `findByEmailAddress`.

Comment: Why in god's name would you want to mock it? Is the findByEmailAddress(...) part of your system under test oder is it part of a dependency?

Comment: To unit test the functionality of findByEmailAddress, I would want to know that it returns Optional.empty when the email address doesn't exist and the selectByEmailAddress is called with the given email address param when it does.  There is no value actually testing the DAO here as it has its own unit tests.